# Neptune GraphQL Specify Deep Tree

Tags: graphql, amazon-neptune

I have this type defined:

```
"Convo object type"
type Convo {
    "The Neptune Conversation identifier"
    id: String
    "A key for the Convo"
    key: String
    "The date the conversation was created"
    createDateTime: String
    "If isHead == true then it is question otherwise a response"
    isHead: Boolean
    "The user id"
    userId: String
    "The category of the conversation"
    threadCategory: String
    "The subject of the conversation"   
    subject: String
    "The text of the conversation"
    content: String
    "Responses to the conversation"
    responses: [Convo]
}
```

I need to return a query and get the conversation and the responses and the responses for those responses.

```
{
    "query" : "{ GetQuestionsForAsset(asset_id: \"11c4d3a7-0ae0-410d-a310-62eb20e8f87f\") {id key createDateTime isHead userId threadCategory subject content responses {id key createDateTime isHead userId threadCategory subject content  } }}"
}
```

I have my graphql schema defined in Python.  I have seen online that I need to use fragments.  Are those defined in the query or in the graphql schema?

Comment: Fragment is a reusable piece of code, define it in schema then use in query https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments

Comment: I defined the fragment in the schema and I am getting this error when referencing the fragment:  Unknown fragment 'responsesField

This is what I have defined for the fragment:
fragment responsesField on Convo {
    responses
}